# Orthonormal system of simultaneous eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose we have a commutative family of compact, self-adjoint operators
on a Hilbert space. Prove that there is an orthonormal system of simultaneous eigenvectors
for the family.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem.  Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Why downvote? $ $ $\ \  $

Answer (score 1):

Since the family is commutative, the operators are simultaneously diagonalizable if one operator is diagonalizable, so it suffices to find a single set of orthonormal eigenvectors for one self-adjoint operator of the family. By spectral theorem, any compact self-adjoint operator on real/complex hilbert space is diagonalizable, so we proved what we want.

Check this page about spectral theorem

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator_on_Hilbert_space

Comment: I have a question.  Is the family of orthonormal eigenvectors supposed to work for all of the operators if it works for one of the operators?  What definition of "commutative" are you using here?

Comment: The family of orthonormal eigenvectors works for all of the operators in the commutative family of compact, self-adjoint operators. The proof of this is can be found in page 19 of this slide. http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Fall08/19.pdf

Comment: @AranKomatsuzaki I don't understand the argument *"Since the family is commutative, the operators are simultaneously diagonalizable if one operator is diagonalizable".* Can you refer to some general theorem? If I take commuting family of matrices containing the identity matrix, are they still simultaneously diagonalizable?

Comment: Ryan Reich explains about that theorem in the following page. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/124779/when-are-two-operators-simultaneously-diagonalisable Yes. They are still simultaneously diagonalizable.